# installing a qt widget for qt designer

Tags: qt, widget, qt-designer

I downloaded a very useful widget for my applications. A LED indicator from http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QLedIndicator?content=118610

But there is no README file or any instruction files.

I unzip it and gave `qmake QLedIndicator.pro`  and then `make` it compiled well without errors.

But I have no idea how to add the widget in Qt Designer, so I can drag and drop it where I need.

I'm using qt 4.8.3 with mingw. qt creator 2.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Linux you just need to copy the file libQLedIndicatorPlugin.so in the

/usr/lib/qt/plugins/designer/

directory (or whatever is the directory on your distro).

Under Windows the process is similar, but you need to pay attention to the building process, as explained on the bottom of the page I linked

Comment: thanks. for your answer. im using windows. I build what i downloaded as i explaned but cant find eny lib or dll to copy to

Comment: did u try adding the plugin

Comment: In windows you should find the plugin in (if I remember) the directory `QLedIndicator/libQLedIndicatorPlugin/{debug|release}/QLedIndicatorPlugin.dll`, but you have to build it manually, the top level .pro file does not build it

Answer (score 2):

Qt's plugin architecture allows you to add custom widget to the designer. You can check out this official qt's link to do so - http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/designer-customwidgetplugin.html

Comment: enyway thanks for ur answer. it gave me an idea. marked as answer. :)